# Any drawback if record a video in file using mpegtsmux muxer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

Currently i am recording a video in file with h265 encoded format. But, one issue(duration issue) is observed during playing a h265 video in h265 player. Issue can be solved, if we use video muxer after encoding and before sink a video (encode-> mpegtsmux -> multifilesink).

My doubt, Is there any drawback to use "mpegtsmux" muxer? I mean any storage related concerns if we store muxing video instead of store h265 video in file. Even this muxing plugin will be required when live streaming feature is added in our solution, future. That's the reason i check all scenarios before  utilise muxer plugin in our solution.

Thanks in advance!